# Why is a list needed for random.choice

Tags: python, list

This is probably a very straight forward question but would love a simple explanation as to the why?

The below code requires a list in order to obtain a random card.

```
 import random
 card = random.choice (["hearts", "clubs", "frogs"])
```

I am puzzled as to why it requires a list and why I cannot do this.

```
import = random
card = random.choice("hearts" , "clubs", "frogs")
```

I'm fine that I can't do it I just would like to know why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

because, the first snippet

```
["hearts","clubs","frogs"]
```

sends only one argument to the function (a list)

while the second one sends three strings to the function. The function `choice` is equipped to take only a single argument. So, you have to send it as a list or anything that can be indexed, so that it chooses a random index to return the value

Comment: Any sort of sequence will do - including strings.

Comment: This reasoning is flawed. If `random.choice` took a variable number of arguments, it would get the arguments in a tuple and the behavior could otherwise be made exactly the same.

Comment: Which is why it's easy to wrap it if one wants that - see my answer below.  The current behavior is an effect of the implementation in cpython.

Comment: actually this function can take only a single argument. So i think you are wrong

Comment: @larsmans: did you try sending multiple arguments to this function? I get an error while trying to do so

Comment: @AswinMurugesh: I'm not saying it takes multiple arguments. I'm saying that it would make hardly any difference if it did.

Comment: ya but that doesnt make my answer a flawed one

Comment: @AswinMurugesh it does. You are basically saying "`choice` takes one argument because it takes one argument" as if it was impossible to create `choice` in such a way that it could take multiple arguments.

Comment: @larsmans may be not accurate, but Aswin's answer is very good for new Python learner like me :) . yes your answer is best answer.

Comment: You could implement `choice()` with multiple arguments but then you would have to check the types of the arguments before choosing to make sure that you don't raise any `TypeError`s. I think they just did this for simplicity's sake.

Comment: @2rs2ts: I don't see why any typechecks would be needed.

Comment: @larsmans If you were implementing it as they do now (choosing between 0 and len() of the argument) then you'd have to merge the collections. Otherwise you'd have to come up with a sort of 2d approach where you add the lens() and choose a collection based on the random choice... I guess you might be able to do it but it would involve more len() checks and extra math, probably less efficient...?

Comment: @2rs2ts Judging from the example, I think the OP would expect `choice` to pick from its arguments rather than from their concatenation.

Comment: @larsmans As would I - I guess he's only asking why he can't do that, though. (I'm just guessing.)

Answer (score 31):

Because of Murphy's law: anything that *can* be done the wrong way *will* be done the wrong way by someone, some day. Your suggested API would require

```
random.choice(*lst)
```

when the values to choose from are in the list (or other sequence) `lst`. When someone writes

```
random.choice(lst)
```

instead, they would always get `lst` back instead of an exception. The Python principle that "explicit is better than implicit" then dictates that we have to type a few extra characters.

(Admitted, the result of `random.choice("foobar")` pointed out by others may be surprising to a beginner, but once you get used to the language you'll appreciate the way that works.)

Comment: +1 for answering the question that the OP was actually asking (I think).

Comment: Can we do like: `random.choice({"foo":1,"bar":2,"spam":3})` **?**

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Looking at the implementation, that'll only work with numerical keys, since `choice` returns `seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]`. You can only do it longhand by `d = {"foo":1, "bar":2, "baz":3}` `d[random.choice(d.keys())]` (or `d[random.choice(list(d.keys()))]` in Py3).

Answer (score 8):

The issue is that you're calling `random.choice` with 3 parameters, not a single parameter with 3 elements. Try `random.choice(('one', 'two', 'three'))` for instance.

Any sequence with a length and a suitable `__getitem__` (for indexing) will do - since it picks a number between 0 and `len(something)` to choose the element.

So you could use a tuple instead if you so wanted.

Comment: Or even a string :) -- `random.choice("foobar")` will randomly pick a character from that string.

Comment: Or `xrange()`; it too has a length and supports indexing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- It'll work, but does `xrange` support all of the sequence methods?  If not, it's not *guaranteed* to work ...

Comment: @mgilson: it is documented as being a [sequence type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange). That is as close as you can get to supporting all the sequence methods. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- So it is!  Fantastic :).

Answer (score 5):

`random.choice` will work for any sequence that supports indexing.

```
>>> random.choice("foobar")              #string
'o'
>>> random.choice(("foo","bar","spam"))  #tuple
'spam' 
>>> random.choice(["foo","bar","spam"])  #list
'spam'
```

Will not work for sets:

```
>>> random.choice({"foo","bar","spam"})
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<ipython-input-313-e97c3088a7ef>", line 1, in <module>
>     random.choice({"foo","bar","spam"})
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 274, in choice
>     return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
> TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing
> ```

In `random.choice("hearts" , "clubs", "frogs")` you actually passed three arguments to `choice`, while `random.choice` expects only one parameter and that too must support indexing.

But `random.choice` can work for dict if the dict has numeric keys(that are between 0 to len(dict)-1), as internally it does something like this:

```
dic[int(random() * len(seq))]
```

Example:

```
>>> dic = dict(zip([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], "abcdef"))
>>> random.choice(dic)
'b'
>>> random.choice(dic)
'd'
>>> random.choice(dic)
'd'
>>> random.choice(dic)    #fails as 0 was not found in dic
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "<ipython-input-366-5cfa0e5f2911>", line 1, in <module>
    random.choice(dic)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 274, in choice
    return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
KeyError: 0
```

Comment: Can we do like: `random.choice({"foo":1,"bar":2,"spam":3})` **?**

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Good point, it can work for dicts if that dict has numeric keys, but those keys must be between `0` to `len(dict)-1`.

Answer (score 4):

There are several good answers above about why `random.choice` is implemented as it is, and why it's actually what you probably want.

You can wrap it yourself easily enough, if you want to be able to call choice with arbitrary numbers of arguments:

```
import random

def random_choice_of_arbitrary_args(*args):
    return random.choice(args)
```

Of course you would probably name it something more concise.

This does have the following surprising behavior:

```
>>> random_choice_of_arbitrary_args([1, 2, 3])
[1, 2, 3]
```

Which is because you're ultimately telling random.choice to give you a random element of a sequence with one element.  So a better implementation might be:

```
import random

def my_choice(*args):
    if len(args) == 1:
        return random.choice(args[0])
    else:
        return random.choice(args)
```

Comment: What about `random_choice_of_arbitrary_args("foobar")`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: `random_choice_of_arbitrary_args(*"foobar")`.

Comment: This is a really good answer because it highlights that the decision to make `choice` what it is isn't a technical one but a psychological one. It would be entirely possible to think of the `choice` that OP mentions, it just happens that that's not how it's implemented.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [the implementation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/random.py#l272).  It picks a random number from `0 to len(input_sequence)` and then uses that index to choose a random item.

Perhaps a better answer is because the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) says that the input has to be a sequence.

Comment: This is honestly a great answer. If you took a variable number of arguments, each of which supported indexing but couldn't be naturally combined (e.g. `"hello" + "world"` vs `"hello" + ["w","o","r","l","d"]`), it would take a lot of work to combine them, or at least require a `try, except` to check for such an error.

Answer (score 0):

Put simply, because that's not how the `random.choice` function was defined. My guess is that the decision was made just because accepting a single iterable argument is a cleaner practice than just a variable number of arbitrary arguments.

Therefore defining the function like this:

```
# This is (approximately) how it's actually written
def choice(iterable):
    #choose from iterable
```

is cleaner than this:

```
# This is kind of ugly
def choice(*args):
    #make sure *args exists, choose from among them.
```

The way it is actually written allows you to pass it one single iterable item of any kind, which is both clean and convenient. **If it was defined the second way**, it would be easy to screw up when using it: someone could call `random.choice([1, 2, 3])` and they would always get back `[1, 2, 3]`!